# Open Form, Wait Close - without input

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am looking for a set of Code That will allow me to display an intro Form/Start up Screen on my Db. 
So I need the form to stay open for about 5 Seconds then close automatically.

I know know how to get the program to load the form I want its the matter of the specific wait time. followed by the `Docmd.close, me.name,acsaveno` then `Docmd.openform` blah blah blah...

I have looked at doing a `DoEvents` loop but that seems to put alot of pressure on the CPU for 5 seconds, Im hoping there is a simpler method.

Thanks everyone for your help before hand.

Answer (score 1):

Set the *TimerInterval* to 5000.

Use the *Timer* event to call some "do next" code and then close the form.